We now have an AI policy
There's now an AI policy.  What you need to know:

At this stage, we haven't banned AI posts (like many other sites).

If you use AI-generated content, it needs to properly referenced.


The thing is, we haven't really had issues with people mindlessly copy/pasting ChatGPT (et al.) content en masse here (it's a major problem at Stack Overflow and other sites).  I think I've seen maybe 2 or 3 such posts in total.
If someone came here posting nonsense (AI-generated or not), downvoting is an effective way to self-moderate (noting the existence of both automatic question and answer bans).  It can be challenging to accurately identify AI-generated posts.

At this time, I probably use AI in my posts more than anyone else here.  Here's my tips (aside from making sure you reference AIs usage):

We all know by now that these AIs can be wrong (e.g. hallucinations); you need to think critically ("what if it's wrong?") and corroborate its claims.  Indeed, AI is best used in conjunction with more traditional resources, like dictionaries, textbooks, databases, etc.

These AIs can help you identify parts of your question/answer which could be improved.  I usually give ChatGPT my whole answer before posting, and ask if it agrees with me and if there's anything I could improve.  Likewise, I usually copy/paste my questions into Google and ChatGPT before posting and see what comes up.

Alternatively, you can write your answer, then ask AI to write its answer, and compare the two.  Perhaps AI points out something you might want to add to your answer.

AI is great at generating example sentences to add to your post; I suggest generating a large number of them (I usually ask for 10 or 20), and picking out the ones that best illustrate your point.  These are usually more helpful for language learners than example sentences found through Google or databases like YouDao, Jukuu, Zaojv, etc., because they are at a reasonable level (e.g. they don't contain random proper nouns), are used in suitable contexts, and include common collocations.

Some AIs (like ChatGPT) excel at multiple languages, so can be quite helpful for cross-language questions, like "Does Chinese have a chengyu which means [idiom] in Japanese?" or "What's the difference between [word] in Chinese and [word] in English?"

At leonardo.ai (and other sites) you can generate images for free.  Sometimes it can help illustrate a sentence if you have an image to go along with it.

If reasonable, consider adding links like this
  [like this](https://chat.openai.com/share/6dd3baf0-dad2-422e-a37d-b67f3b61f9cc)

to whole conversations with AI.  You can get the URL with ChatGPT by clicking the three-dot icon, and selecting "More/Share/Copy Link").


There's also a GenAI Stack Exchange where you can ask questions about generative AI.

PS.  See also:

Do we want to allow answers written wholly by e.g. ChatGPT?

Examples of an AI (Sage) answering questions at Chinese.SE [reference post]


